# Reading system files with perl without issuing extra seek syscalls on open

Tags: linux, perl, file-io, seek, procfs

I'm trying to use perl to parse some pseudo files from `/proc`  and `/sys` linux pseudo filesystems ([procfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) and [sysfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs)). Such files are unlike regular files - they are implemented by custom file operation handlers. Most of them have zero size for `stat`, some can't be open for read, other can't be written. Sometimes they are implemented incorrectly (which is error, but it is already in the kernel) and I still want to read them directly from perl without starting some helper tools.

There is quick example of reading `/proc/loadavg` with perl, this file is implemented correctly:

```
perl -e 'open F,"</proc/loadavg"; $_=<F>; print '
```

With `strace` of the command I can check how perl implements `open` function:

```
$ strace perl -e 'open F,"</proc/loadavg"; $_=<F>; print ' 2>&1 | egrep -A5 ^open.*loadavg

open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)         = 3
ioctl(...something strange...)    = -1 ENOTTY
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
```

There is `lseek` system call used by `open` perl function.

With strace of `cat /proc/loadavg` there was no extra `seek`-typed system calls:

```
$ strace cat /proc/loadavg 2>&1 | egrep -A2 ^open.*loadavg
open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)         = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fadvise64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL) = 0
```

The special file I want to read (or write) misimplement `seek` file operations and will not give any useful data to `read` (or to `write`) syscall after `seek`.

Is there way of opening files for reading in perl5 (no external modules) without calling extra `lseek`? (and without using `system("cat < /proc/loadavg")`)

Is there way of opening files for writing in perl5 without calling extra `lseek`?

There is sysopen, but it does extra lseek too: `perl -e 'use Fcntl;sysopen(F,"/proc/loadavg",O_RDONLY);sysread(F,$_,2048); print '`

Comment: On the linux box on which I tried it, `open F, "<:unix", "/proc/loadavg"` does just `fstat` and set close on exec

Comment: @ikegami, What kind of black magic (`<:unix`) is used in your answer (doc or source link may be useful)? It didn't seek on my test linux too.

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation for [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), PerlIO layers are documented in [PerlIO](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html).

Comment: Check out `perl -MPerlIO -E'open F, "<", $ARGV[0] or die $!; say for PerlIO::get_layers(\*F);' ~/.bashrc`, then try again specifying `:unix`.

Comment: @ikegame, there is still `fstat` with `my $SET,">:unix",".../driver_command; print $SET $COMMAND."\n"; close $SET`; can I disable it? My script still not able to communicate with driver; but plain `echo SAME_COMMAND > .../driver_command` works, I see only extra fstat here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noticed, Perl's builtin `open` masks quite a bit of magic. If that magic gets in your way, there is `sysopen` and `POSIX::open()` that offer decreasing degrees of magic. `POSIX::open()` is sufficiently non-magical that it returns file descriptors rather than Perl filehandles, and you have to use `POSIX::read()` instead of the normal Perl operators to get data from it. If that's not raw enough for your circumstances, you may be out of luck.

The `POSIX` module is a part of the core perl distribution since the very first release of Perl 5, so if you don't have it your Perl installation is crippled.

Comment: Calle, please, add some links to documentation. ikegami recommended `<:unix` black magic option for open, can you add it as other alternative solution to your answer?

Comment: Calle, thanks, POSIX::open + read works without any extra syscalls: `perl -e 'use POSIX (); $fd=POSIX::open("/proc/loadavg");$bytes = POSIX::read( $fd, $buf, 30 ); POSIX::close($fd);print $bytes." read: ".$buf;' with result `27 read: 0.16 0.09 0.02 ....`

Comment: There is '\0' special char in end of the read. How can I parse multiline from POSIX::read, there is no  `while(<FILE>)` now.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna go really low-level and avoid even the `mmap` from `POSIX::open()` (and also avoid loading the huge `POSIX` module), perform the `syscall()`s yourself. Probably want to `require syscall.ph` to get the values of `SYS_open` and `SYS_read` if you don't know them (*for me* I know `read`, `write`, and `open` are `0`,`1`,`2`, respectively - this is important to know for the `syscall` function below).

The following code:

```
strace perl -mPOSIX -e'$fd=POSIX::open("/proc/loadavg");POSIX::read($fd, 
$_, 9999);' 2>&1 | egrep -A2 '^open.*loadavg'
```

gives something like (for me `open()` is `openat()`)

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY) = 3
mmap(NULL, 135168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) =             
0x7f2389f0d000
read(3, "1.22 2.51 1.54 3/206 18145\n", 9999) = 27
```

Try something like this:

```
strace perl -MFcntl -E'$p="/proc/loadavg"; $fd=syscall 2, $p, O_RDONLY; $bf = 
"\0"x50; syscall 0, $fd, $bf, 50' 2>&1 | egrep -A1 '^open.*loadavg'
```

and get:

```
open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "0.45 0.18 0.20 2/241 12349\n", 50) = 27
```

**EDIT**:
Regarding the [comment from @osgx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40372677/reading-system-files-with-perl-without-issuing-extra-seek-syscalls-on-open#comment68810947_40398468),

> There is `\0` special char in end of the read. How can I parse multiline from POSIX::read, there is no `while(<FILE>)` now.

Note that when you '`while(<FILE>)`' you are really just calling `read()` one byte at a time and checking for the `'\n'` char--or whatever your `$/` (input record seperator) is set to (you can confirm this via `strace`).

Thus, a simple loop to check for `$/` could suffice. (Note that `read()` returns, on success, the number of bytes read (0 indicates EOF). Here is a crude example of a single "`readline`":

```
require 'syscall.ph';
require Fcntl;
my($path, $fd, $buf, $res);
$path = '/proc/meminfo';
$fd = syscall SYS_open(), $path, O_RDONLY;
$buf = ' ';
$res = '';
$res .= $buf while syscall SYS_read(), $fd, $buf, 1 and $buf ne $/;
syscall SYS_close(), $fd; # optional in this case
```

Just be aware that *if* you are going for *portability* of any sort, `syscall`-ing is probably one of the worst choices, but that's the price of specificity. (`POSIX::open/read/close()` isn't better by much in this sense either.). To maintain portability, you might be better off using [@ikegami's comment (<:unix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40372677/reading-system-files-with-perl-without-issuing-extra-seek-syscalls-on-open#comment67999725_40372677), and ignore the extra calls to `fstat` and `fcntl`;

Comment: "read, write, and open are 0,1,2" Are they always 0,1, and 2, for any of linux platform?

Comment: Nope; using syscalls directly isn't the most portable. Try `require syscall.ph` to find out what the `SYS_read`, `SYS_write`, `SYS_open` constants are for you. Sidenote: I didn't method anything about closing the file descriptor. You _can_ use `POSIX::close()`, but you could also use `syscall(SYS_close,$fd)`,(which is `syscall(3,$fd)` for me).